# Unobtrusive validation ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

in my app I have modified my script files in order to allow comma as decimal separator instead of using a dot (issue related to localization).

The thing is, when I use the unmodified script (the min version) the validation works fine... the error messages displays instantaneously and dissapear also instantaneously on correct. But when I use the modified version (non min version), the error messages just won't show up until I hit the submit button, then the MVC flow occurs (controller->action->view) and the ModelState.isValid goes false, display the same view with the model and obviously the model errors added, with the unobtrusive message sided to the incorrect field. I then correct the value, I know the value is fine, but the message doesn't clear. With the error message still on screen I hit on submit, then the MVC cycle occurs without errors, with a successful end.

Does any of you know how to fix this? I don't know if I should generate a min version or extend that min version overwriting the function. I don't even know how to do another thing different from the one I've done.

Comment: Did you find the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't make this work as I expected... I just used the non .min version... several blogs in Internet use the same approach to make modifications, or use plugins with lots of jquery scripts (this approach of plugins is what I tried to avoid, because it makes really hard to give maintenance!)